# Model Key Path issue with view-based NSTableView

Tags: xcode, key, nstableview, cocoa-bindings

When setting up bindings to work with `NSTableView` I'm coming across a problem. My array controller is bound to my table controller and its model key path is the array I'm using to populate the table. I've also set up one key, called `name`.

My table view is bound to my array controller and the Controller Key is set to `arrangedObjects`. Finally, the `NSTextField` is bound to the Table Cell View, and this is where the problem lies. When I try to input my model key path, I can input `objectValue`, however when I go to add `.name` I get a 'No completions found' tooltip appear.

Why is my key not being pulled through to the NSTableView binding?

I should add I've followed the Apple documentation to the letter however it still doesn't pull through my key.

Answer (score 0):

The intermediate TableCellView object is "breaking" the link between the key you added to the NSArrayController and your controls. I wouldn't worry about it. If you know the keyPath is correct, just enter it, even if there's no auto-completion. It would be nice if Xcode were smart enough to automagically bridge that gap, but I don't consider it a "red flag" that it doesn't. I've certainly had plenty of cases that work just fine despite auto-complete not filling in the key.